# How to post like the picture?

Tags: wordpress

I want to take post from themplate static and post it in theme wordpress and make it dinamic.

I know how to post simple post which contain two element:

1. Title text.
2. paragraph text.

but in my case the post have a style diffrant from simple post.

The static code html which I want to convert it to post theme:

```
<section id="content">
    <div class="container_16">
        <div class="p10">
            <article class="grid_4">
                <h4>Honeymoons:</h4> 
                <div class="txt-1">Praesent vestibulum aenean Nonummy hendrerit mauris.</div>
                <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes ascetur ridiculus
                mus. Nulla dui. Fusce feugiat malesuada odio.</p> <a href="#" class="link-1">read more</a>
            </article>
            <article class="grid_4">
                <h4>Honeymoons:</h4> 
                <div class="txt-1">Praesent vestibulum aenean Nonummy hendrerit mauris.</div>
                <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes ascetur ridiculus
                mus. Nulla dui. Fusce feugiat malesuada odio.</p> <a href="#" class="link-1">read more</a>
            </article>
            <article class="grid_4">
                <h4>Honeymoons:</h4> 
                <div class="txt-1">Praesent vestibulum aenean Nonummy hendrerit mauris.</div>
                <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes ascetur ridiculus
                mus. Nulla dui. Fusce feugiat malesuada odio.</p> <a href="#" class="link-1">read more</a>
            </article>
        </div>
</section>
```

How can I add tag html to post as you can see in the below code : ?

1. `<article class="grid_4">`
2. <`h4>here is the title:</h4>`
3. `<div class="txt-1">`
4. `<p>`

the style:

[image]

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think from your question you are looking for something like the code below;

```
<section id="content">
    <div class="container_16">
        <div class="p10">

        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>     

            <article class="grid_4">


                    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>

                    <div class="txt-1"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>

                    <?php the_content(); ?>

                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="link-1">read more</a>


            </article>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

That will certainly help you get going.  Note you have omitted a closing `</div>` tag.

You might want to look at a custom WP_Query rather than just a standard Wordpress Loop, so you can pull the 3 latest posts out of your blog, or pull posts from a specific category.